# How can I deploy my windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have just updated my Visual Studio Professional 2013 with update 2 RC. I made a simple app to try. I choose to release and click the build button in projects but it isn't work for creating xxxx.appx file. It's creating xxx.exe and other files.

How can I create .appx package in 8.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like windows phone 8.0 apps for windows phone store 8.1 apps there is no.xap file is created  after running the app.Windows phone store 8.1 apps are deployed through windows store with .appx file.So that you have to right click on the on project, go to store, create app package.You wont get a xap but an appx, which is the new xap.
For more info see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f12b250e-0799-4595-ab12-bf26131e249a/no-xap-file-being-generated?forum=wptools#4661ad6e-d434-4df8-8de9-2723fae7fa78